# mocha/chai test Unexpected token =>

Tags: mocha.js, chai

I'm running a test, and I'm getting an unexpected error.

I'm sorting the results:

```
        docs.sort((a, b) => m_ids.findIndex(id => a._id.equals(id)) - 
            m_ids.findIndex(id => b._id.equals(id)));
```

The error I'm getting is definitely related to that line

```
mbp:test testlab$ mocha .
/Users/testlab/Documents/workspace/KBase/controller/KBase.js:112
                docs.sort((a, b) => m_ids.findIndex(id => a._id.equals(id)) - 
                                 ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
```

I was thinking about skipping the code by putting an if statement around it, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: What version does the `node --version` command report?

Comment: I get v0.12.7. It does work in Node. It is just when I run a test.

Comment: It is funny. This code isn't called during the test, so it is all in the compiler of mocha (I think)

Comment: How do you have mocha installed? And which version?

Comment: I have it installed globally. The version I have is: 3.0.2

Comment: From my old C days, I added code to try and skip it, but it won't really allow a ifdef

Comment: Are you using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to manage multiple versions of node? Regardless of that, try installing it locally and running it as `./node_modules/.bin/mocha .`

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the sort to not use =>, so it is working on the webpage and it is working on chai/mocha now.